# How to resolve "render method has not been called" on failed jest test (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

Writing a component test but test fails with an error of *"render method has not been called."*

`MealCard.test.tsx`

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react-native"
import { MealCard } from "../src/components/MealCard";

describe("testing MealCard component", () => {
    test("open menu with edit and delete options", () => {
        const testItem ={
            image: 'null',
            name: 'testing', 
            id: 'name+date',
            calories: 2000,
            proteins: 150,
            carbohydrates: 200, 
            fats: 90, 
        }

        fireEvent.press(screen.getByTestId("moreMenuTrigger"), "onMenuOpen")
        expect(screen.getByText("Edit")).toBeDefined();
        expect(screen.getByText("Delete")).toBeDefined();

        render(
            <MenuProvider>
                <MealCard key ="testing" item={testItem}/>
            </MenuProvider>
        )
    })
})
```

also its my first time writing a component test, im not sure if there is a better way to test *if a menu will open with edit and delete options upon clicking icon*, if so i would like any suggested improvements. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to `render(<MenuProvider...)` first and only then `fireEvent.press(...`